# Import JS Dictionary to Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

I am very new to Julia Lang (in fact, just trying it instead of Python for some data analysis). However, I am stuck when loading my data.

My data is from a web-application built using ReactJS/ Python, saved in a csv. I get the data into a Julia DataFrame. The cell in this DataFrame that I need to analyse looks like this:

```
{'isClicked': [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True], 'continuation': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

This comes from a JS-dictionary. Is there a way to convert it into a dictionary in Julia? I have tried a JSON3 converter (https://discourse.julialang.org/t/why-does-julia-not-support-json-syntax-to-create-a-dict/42873/20), but it seems not to work because of the single quotation mark. I.e., the error I get is:

> ArgumentError: invalid JSON at byte position 2 while parsing type
> JSON3.Object: ExpectedOpeningQuoteChar {'isClicked': [True, True,

Any suggestion are highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JSON requires double quotes instead of single quotes. Try

```
replace(text, "'" => "\"")
```

before sending it to the JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a JSON dictionary, it's a python one. In Python you should do

```
import json
with open('dict_file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_py_dict, f)
```

Then in Julia

```
import JSON
my_julia_dict = JSON.parsefile("dict_file.json")
```